# Get nested element's attribute value via click event listener

Tags: javascript, html

In a `JavaScript` build, I have a hyperlink the user can click to send a message. When this link is clicked, attributes on that `anchor tag` are sent to a `click event listener`, which uses those attribute values to fill in portions of the message (where the message came from, etc.).

The problem: the `anchor tag` contains a nested `<svg>` element (small image). If the user clicks the anchor text, no problem, message sends with attribute data. But if the user clicks the `<svg>` image next to the anchor text, these attributes don't get sent, causing errors:

**Anchor tag:**

```
 <a class="my-anchor-class"
    my-attribute-id="{{ thing.id }}"
    my-attribute-title="{{ thing.title }}""
    href="#myHref">
     <svg>
         <use xlink:href="#myMessageSvg"/>
     </svg>    
     Send Me A Message
 </a>
```

**Click event listener:**

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var myElement = event.target;

    if (myElement.classList.contains('my-anchor-class')) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var myId = stripTheHtml(myElement.getAttribute('my-attribute-id'));
        var myTitle = stripTheHtml(myElement.getAttribute('my-attribute-title'));

        messages.setAttribute('action', MY_ACTION + myId);
        messagesTitle.innerHTML = 'Re: ' + myTitle;
    }
});
```

When `<a>`'s `Send Me A Message` text is clicked, all works fine. But if the `<svg>` image is clicked instead, attribute values don't get sent and action fails. I've tried adding the same attributes and class from `<a>` onto the `<svg>` element to no avail - still the same error. Does anyone know how to get a click of my `<svg>` image to work the same as clicking its parent's `<a>` text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the event target for the element tagName. If it is not 'A', use the target's parent element as the source. Otherwise, the target must be the correct element.

Note I set the event handler on the anchor tag itself.

```js
document.querySelector('.my-anchor-class').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let myElement = event.target;
  while (myElement.tagName !== 'A') {
    myElement = myElement.parentElement;
  }
  console.log(myElement.getAttribute('my-attribute-id'));

});
```

```html
<a class="my-anchor-class" my-attribute-id="thing.id" my-attribute-title="thing.title" href="#myHref">
  <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="75" height="75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="60" fill="blue" />
</svg> Send Me A Message
</a>
```